# how can i get the current displayed div id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get the the blocked div id in jquery

**HTML**

```
 <div id="USDC1" style="" class="tablegraphview">USDC2</div>
 <div id="USDC2" style="display:none" class="tablegraphview">USDC2</div>
 <div id="USDC3" style="display:none" class="tablegraphview">USDC3</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function tablegraphview(){
var getid = $('.tablegraphview').attr('id');
alert(getid);
}
```

for ex

```
<div id="USDC2" style="display:block" class="tablegraphview">USDC2</div>
```

I need to current div id how can i do that in jquery

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by `current displayed div`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `$(this).is(':visible')`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="USDC1" style="" class="tablegraphview">USDC2</div>
<div id="USDC2" style="display:none" class="tablegraphview">USDC2</div>
<div id="USDC3" style="display:none" class="tablegraphview">USDC3</div>

<script>
$(function() {

    $(".tablegraphview").each( function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

---

Or

As per @pieter command

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="USDC1" style="" class="tablegraphview">USDC2</div>
    <div id="USDC2" style="display:none" class="tablegraphview">USDC2</div>
    <div id="USDC3" style="display:none" class="tablegraphview">USDC3</div>
    
    <script>
    $(function() {
    
     alert($(".tablegraphview:visible").attr('id'));
    
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You can simplify your code by using the `:visible` as a selector: `$(".tablegraphview:visible").attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector

```
 $('div').not('[style*="display:none"]')
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/9yq14dd7/)